# How to make the & sign blue if it is a reference sign?

Tags: c++, ide, visual-studio-code, textmate

[image]

```
template<typename T>
void f(T const&& n1, T const& n2)
{
    T&& x1 = static_cast<T&&>(n1);
    T&  x2 = static_cast<T&>(n2);
}
```

The snapshot is from `Visual Studio Code` with `C/C++` extensions.

**Problems**

*1. In `T&& n1` and `T& n2`, `&` signs are blue.*

*2. In `T&& x1` and `T& x2`, `&` signs are white.*

*3. In `<T&&>` and `<T&>`, `&` signs are white.*

**Questions**

*1. How to make the `&` sign blue if it is a reference sign?*

*2. Is it possible via modifying one of the following?*

- *editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations*
- *editor.tokenColorCustomizations*
- *cpp.tmLanguage.json*

Comment: ¿I guess using normal Visual Studio IDE is not an option?

Comment: Find the TextMate scopes of the blue and white parts and modify the color of these scopes in your settings

Comment: why not also paste the code as text also, now we have to type this to try it out

Comment: The source code is pasted. @rioV8

Comment: the non-blue `&`'s are `keyword.operator` the blue `&` is a `storage.modifier.reference`, you can file an issue with the C++ extension to also detect references in all typenames, or edit `cpp.tmLanguage.json` yourself

Comment: I don't know how to modify *cpp.tmLanguage.json*, could you paste a modified version as an answer? Thanks in advance. @rioV8

Comment: The same problem is with the `T` in the `template<T>` it has a different color/scope than the body use of `T`, there is no AST used to determine the TextMate scopes, it is all done with regex. modify `cpp.tmLanguage.json` will not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Based on rioV8's comments).

In C++, `&` has different meanings depending on context. It can be the address-operator, it can denote a reference, it can also be a binary bit-and operator. To distinguish all these, you need to **parse** the tokens next to it. `&&` is only marginally simpler, it can't be a unary operator.

In `T & x`, you need to know if `T` is a type or a value. That requires applying C++ name lookup rules on `T`. We can see in your example that it's `typename T`. However, Visual Studio Code does not parse C++ to color the text, and therefore gets the category wrong. You cannot fix this; this needs to be fixed by Microsoft.